# INotifyPropertyChanged within child bindinglists

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, inotifypropertychanged, bindinglist

I have a parent class (implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`), that has a Property that is a bindinglist of (`ChildClass`).
The `ChildClass` also implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

If I bind something to the parentclass, it correctly reflects changes to the parentclass properties - with the exception of changes to:

1. The number of elements in the `BindingList(of ChildClass)` [as a result of adding or deleting items in the list]. OR
2. A change in a property of an item in the `BindingList(of ChildClass)`

If I bind something directly to an item of `ChildClass` (i.e. an item in the `BindingList(Of ChildClass)`) - that works too.

How to wire this up so #1 and #2 are appropriately reflected in bound objects?

Here's the vb version of Paul's great answer. Without the `List_Changed` event, changes to the `BindingList` were not being correctly propagated up the chain in a nested business object. With it, they are!

```
Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
Private WithEvents m_children As IBindingList

Public Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName()> Optional ByVal propertyName As String = Nothing)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub

Public Property Children As IBindingList
    Get
        Return m_children
    End Get
    Set
        m_children = Value
        NotifyPropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub m_children_ListChanged(sender As Object, e As ListChangedEventArgs) Handles m_children.ListChanged
    NotifyPropertyChanged(NameOf(Children))
End Sub
```

Comment: Show us some code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BindingList<T>` proovides the event [`BindingList<T>.ListChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132742(v=vs.110).aspx) that

> Occurs when the list or an item in the list changes.

You can easily implement an event-handler in your parent class and wire it up to `ListChanged`. (I've assumed the children property - the `BindingList<ChildClass>` - to be named `Children`)

```
private void Children_OnListChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Children));
}
```

With `OnPropertyChanged` you can notify subscribers, that the `Children`property has changed. If there is no implementation in your class, yet, it may look like the following

```
private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

where `[CallerMemberName]` (which lives in `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` namespace) is a  hint for the compiler to use the name of the property that has called `OnPropertyChanged` if no explicit value is passed.

Comment: Phenomenal. Just Plain Works. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help :)